# Finite groups such that non-central, commuting elements have the same stabilizer

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let me say that a finite, non-abelian group $G$ *has the property* $(P)$ if

> for any two elements $x, \, y \in G - Z(G)$ such that $y \in C_G(x)$, one has $C_G(y)=C_G(x)$.

For instance, it is easy to see that both the dihedral group $D_8$ and the quaternion group $Q_8$ have the property $(P)$.

Instead, the symmetric group $S_n$, with $n \geq 5$, does not have it: indeed, setting $x=(1\, 2)$, $y=(3 \,4)$, we have $y \in C_G(x)$, but $C_G(y) \neq C_G(x)$, since $(2 \, 5) \in C_G(y)$ but $(2 \, 5) \notin C_G(x)$.

I am not an expert in Group Theory (actually, I was led to consider these groups by studying a problem in Algebraic Geometry) and I suspect that this property is already known. So, let me ask the following

> **Question.** Was property $(P)$ already studied in the literature? Is there a classification of groups having the property $(P)$, at least for small order? If this is the case, what are relevant references?

Comment: When the center is trivial it's known as "commutative-transitive". Your property, satisfied by $\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ for any field, passes to subgroups. In particular, for $K$ field of characteristic $2$, $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$ is commutative-transitive.

Comment: Also $S_4$ doesn't satisfy the property: $(1234)$ commutes to its square $(13)(24)$, which commutes to $(12)(34)$ but $(1234)$ and $(12)(34)$ don't commute; similarly $A_6$ is not commutative-transitive. Still $A_4$ and $A_5$ are commutative-transitive.

Comment: @YCor: If it passes to subgroups, it should remain true for $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$ for any field. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, your property is true for $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$. What characteristic 2 ensures is that the center is trivial.

Comment: Ah, ok. Commutative-transitive means that the commutativity relation is transitive on $G-\{1\}$, and if $Z(G)$ is non-trivial this implies that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Well one often assumes commutative-transitive to imply center-free... which makes it only pass to center-free subgroups (= subgroups that are not non-trivial abelian) too. In any case you provided examples showing that your property can be interesting for non-abelian groups with non-trivial center.

Comment: There's a large quantity of 2-step nilpotent groups with your property. For instance the free 2-step nilpotent group of exponent $p$ (odd prime) on $2$ generators has this property.

Comment: @YCor: many thanks. As I said in the question, I am not an expert, in fact I do not know this terminology ("free 2-step nilpotent group"). Could you please provide some introductory reference?

Comment: I have no idea of a reference, it's just familiarity playing with these groups. (Still you reach literature if you search "commutative-transitive group" or so.)

Comment: When $Z(G) = 1$ and $G$ is finite, his means that $G$ is a $CA$-group (group in which each non-identity element  has Abelian centralizer). Simple $CA$-groups were studied and classified by M. Suzuki in the 1950s and 60s. For such groups which are not simple, I am not sure about the extent of the literature, but others might be. However, if $Z(G)$ is non-trivial, the problem becomes rather different.

Comment: I’d be curious to hear the algebro-geometric motivation behind this question

Comment: @SantanaAfton: groups with property (P) cannot be finite quotients (+ a little extra condition) of some surface braid groups. I'm studying these quotients in order to construct some fibred algebraic surface, in the spirit of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01363

Comment: It's always interesting when distinct communities use distinct terminology for the same notion (CA-group vs commutative-transitive). Btw CA-group is largely used by people studying (infinite) locally finite groups. Note: both CA-group and ZCA-group (OP's definition) are obviously (finitely axiomatizable) first-order properties, and in particular they pass to ultraproducts, as well as their negations.